# Arcpy Spatial Join- points within a distance of lines

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to perform a spatial join to join attributes from a point feature layer to the attributes of a line feature layer where the points are within a specified distance of the lines (so that these attributes can later be used in an update cursor). Currently, I am receiving a '000561: Relationship invalid for selected layers' error while trying to run this piece in Visual Studio. A spatial join based on distance between point and line features appears to work without a hitch in ArcMap and ModelBuilder. I would like to avoid field mapping if possible, but maybe that is something I may need to add in.

What am I missing?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.OverwriteOutput = True

defaultGdbPath = 'C:\Topo_Check_Tess_V5.gdb'

#lines
transLayer='C:\Topo_Check_Tess_V5.gdb\Transmission'

#points
ppLayer='C:\Topo_Check_Tess_V5.gdb\PP'


#Make feature layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ppLayer, "ppLayerGU")

#Make feature layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(transLayer, "transLayerGU")

#output join fc
pp_trans_GUJoin ='C:\Topo_Check_Tess_V5.gdb\pp_trans_GU_SpatialJoin'

#spatial join of feature layers
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis ("transLayerGU", "ppLayerGU", 
pp_trans_GUJoin,'JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE','KEEP_ALL','WITHIN_A_DISTANCE',.000002)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you shouldn't have to use field mappings. There is a typo in your code, however.

Remember that the format for SpatialJoin is

`SpatialJoin_analysis (target_features, join_features, out_feature_class, {join_operation}, {join_type}, {field_mapping}, {match_option}, {search_radius}, {distance_field_name})`,

The error is coming from the software parsing your options as:

field_mapping:'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE'

match_option: .000002

Since .000002 is clearly not a valid match option, the code fails. ArcGIS Pro help notes that using "#" or "" is how you skip over the optional arguments if you don't need them, or referencing the optional arguments by name. [Link](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/using-tools-in-python.htm)

You may still require field mappings if there are multiple points to be joined to each line, however.

Refs:
Spatial Join: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm

Tools in ArcPy: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/using-tools-in-python.htm

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and 10.4 and '#' works beautifully. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem! I use 10.4 most of the time, but the code samples and guides in the Pro websites are excellent.